# Unable to create a table

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

```
  udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="MyApp", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
    session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="xxxxxx", username="xxx",
                              password="123456", authentication="LDAP")
    
    DF.to_sql(con=session, name='databasename.tablename', index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

> However the above connection method also doesn't work well.

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE
> type='table' AND name=?;': (3707, "[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata
> Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error, expected something like '('
> between the 'type' keyword and '='.")

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: try to remove `;`

Comment: As the error implies `type` is a reserved keyword in Teradata. But the Select seems to be based on `sqlite` as it tries to access a table named  **sqlite_master**

Comment: If you do have a column with the (horrible) name of `type`, you can use double quotes - `where "type" = 'table'...`.  Probably have to the same thing with `name`.

Comment: The most obvious things: 1: The connection should be a sqlalchemy connectable not a DBI connection (which is why metadata query is not Teradata-specific). 2: For qualified names, you should use separate "schema" parameter for the databasename. 3: Instead of legacy _teradata_ package (udaExec) you should probably be using _teradatasqlalchemy_ (which will also include current _teradatasql_ driver package).